# Keep banner responsive at any time as browser windows increase

Tags: html, css, banner

I'm trying to make my banner expand smoothly as I increase the windows size of my browser to the right.

At one point, I see the black gap showed.

That black gap show on `Note 8` and `Pixel XL`.

[image]

This is the CSS that I got on the page now

```
.respheader{
    background-image: url({{asset('uploads/client/'.$data->Header->site_banner) }});
    background-size:cover;
}


@media only screen and  (min-width: 1024px) {

    .respheader{
        background-image: url({{asset('uploads/client/'.$data->Header->site_banner) }});
        background-size:cover;
    }

}
```

You can see more CSS from here

http://dips.awsri.com/

The issue is there right now.

How would one go about and debug this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change **background-size:contain** to **background-size:cover** in your media queries.

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

**background-size contain**:
Scales the image as large as possible without cropping or stretching the image.

**background-size cover**:
Scales the image as large as possible without stretching the image. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.

Comment: I'm confuse, your suggestion told me to do what I already did `background-size:cover;`

Comment: @kyo check your media queries That is where in your screen shot it shows "background-size contain"